# NetBeans loses control of the JBoss EAP server after you start it

Tags: netbeans, jboss, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins, jboss-forge

I installed the plugin JBoss Forge Plugin to NetBeans, but when you start JBoss EAP through NetBeans, the server starts successfully, but the control does not come back to netbeans and an error panel will be shown: starting of server has time out.

What can this be?

- NetBeans 8.1
- JDK 1.8
- JBoss EAP 6.4

Comment: I face the same issue with NetBeans 8.2 and JBOSS EAP 6.4. @Pereira, have you found the solution to this issue? Adding more details from my side, My port offset is 0. While adding server HTTP port is set to 8080 and management port to 9990. In my standalone xml also port numbers are same. Tool -> Options -> Proxy Settings is set to 'No Proxy'. Right click on server -> Properties -> Platform -> 'Use IDE proxy settings' is unchecked.

Comment: Even i got the same issue with Netbeans... Any solution can be appreciated